# How do I configure a Visual Studio C# unit test solution to accept different runtime configurations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, configuration, runtime

### What I have

I have a unit test Visual Studio C# Solution (which runs webdriver tests, not that that's necessarily relevant). It runs via TeamCity. Currently the environment is hard-coded to "Dev" in one of the .cs files, and I manually change the code locally to run elsewhere when required.

### What I want

A way to setup two projects in TeamCity - one to run on "Dev" environment and the other on "Test" environment. Obviously I can't use hard-coded values so I need some sort of set of configuration files that can be chosen at runtime, or possibly some sort of build parameters - but I have no clue how to do this or what will work.

(I didn't mention TeamCity in the question as it is not 100% relevant / just provides context --- as long as I can run the unit tests eg from the command prompt with parameters that can be passed in, that would do the trick.)

### What I've tried

From what I've asked around, I don't believe I can use web.config as it's not a web solution but a unit test solution. I believe there is a mechanism to tell Configuration Manager what web.config file to use, so I'm hoping there's a similar mechanism that can be used for Unit Test projects. I've tried hunting down information on "build configurations" on "unit test projects" and a range of other searches, but it's a nightmare finding anything relevant.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm good with my basic programming, but if it requires messing around with configurations or build parameters, then I might need a more explicit 'how-to' from you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you familiar with how to use the .config file use the `App.Cong` file and put your setting under an `<appSettings></appSettings>`

Comment: Thanks @MethodMan.  This allows a single config file that I can change.  Unfortunately, I'm looking for a way to *switch* configs based on command-line options (or something else external to modifying a file (including configs).  I need to be able to run different configurations from TeamCity without modifying what's in the config each time I run it.

Comment: When you build on the server, you could define a symbol that can be checked with a #if.

Comment: then use a .INI file or do a google search on how to read from different app.config files at runtime I do not see why you can't just add different keys in a single config file depending on a particular environment I do this all the time.. do a google search on `Compiler Directives` is your best bet

Comment: If I understand correctly, compiler directives / #if statements still require me to change something every time I run the unit tests.  I'm not running these two options FROM different environments - I'm running the tests OVER different environments.  The server, build process, env variables, etc, are all identical.  The only difference is whether my unit tests open a browser with a "h ttps://test.xxxxxx" or a "h ttps://dev.xxxxxx".  Hence my need to run the unit test dll from TeamCity / command line with different parameters / configs passed.

Comment: I *think* I may have solved the problem.  Trying this....   https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Answer (score 0):

Check this extension for Visual Studio
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859

This allows you to create different config files for different build type. You need to create different build types each with a config file specific to that build type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as per my comments above, I tried a solution here:  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

IT WORKED.

I'm now able to create App.Config transforms that automatically link to a Build Configuration.  I can then specify the build configuration inside TeamCity.

The only trick was that the "Rebuild" target didn't work if there were no code changes but there was a difference in Configuration.  (They use the same directory of the same Agent, and a rebuild is necessary).  The workaround for this is to tick the 'Clean all files before build' option in TeamCity Version Control settings.